# How to use Block in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am using block in objective C like

```
typedef void (^RequestSuccessCallback)(WebRequestManager *request);
@property (nonatomic,copy) RequestSuccessCallback RequestSuccessBlock;
```

but how to use Block in swift?

Comment: You're asking very basic questions that would only require a cursory look around the web/stackoverflow. There are plenty of good resources on blocks in Swift out there. In future, please show what attempts you have made at solving your problems, especially when they are this basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
typealias RequestSuccessCallback = (WebRequestManager) -> Void
var requestSuccessBlock: RequestSuccessCallback
```

Or something like this if you prefer a named callback:

```
typealias RequestSuccessCallback = (manager: WebRequestManager) -> Void
var requestSuccessBlock: RequestSuccessCallback
```